# Is there any way to use pug compiler in template section of .vue file

Tags: nativescript-vue

As per title, is there a method to use pug in nativescript-vue?

i tried adding pug and pug-plain-loader to project and modify webpack.config.js with

```
            {
              test: /\.pug$/,
              loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
            }
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: How does your template look like? It should be working because those are the steps to add it. Then `<template lang="pug">`...